# In HTTP Signatures, should I use 'request-line' or 'target-request'?

Tags: node.js, joyent, http-signature

I'm looking at the [Readme.md](https://github.com/joyent/node-http-signature/blob/master/http_signing.md) for http-signing that is part of Joyent's [node-http-signature](https://github.com/joyent/node-http-signature) module, and it says to use a "special name" to include the HTTP request target into the signature base:

> To include the HTTP request line in the signature calculation, use the special request-line value. While this is overloading the definition of headers in HTTP linguism, the request-line is defined in RFC 2616, and as the outlier from headers in useful signature calculation, it is deemed simpler to simply use request-line than to add a separate parameter for it.

Including `request-line` would imply including text like `POST /url/path/here HTTP/1.1` into the signature base.

Conversely [draft 03 of the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-03) says to use a different "special value" to include the request target:

> If the header field name is `(request-target)` then generate the header field value by concatenating the lowercased :method, an ASCII space, and the :path pseudo-headers

Yes, (request-target) in parens.

---

With the former, the signature base for a request might look like:

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1 + "\n"
date: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 20:51:35 GMT + "\n"
content-type: application/json + "\n"
content-md5: h0auK8hnYJKmHTLhKtMTkQ==
```

...whereas with the latter, the signature base for the same request would look like this:

```
(request-target): POST /foo + "\n"
date: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 20:51:35 GMT + "\n"
content-type: application/json + "\n"
content-md5: h0auK8hnYJKmHTLhKtMTkQ==
```

So which is authoritative?  I doubt that there will remain two ways to include the method and path into the signature base.

I suspect "implementations rule", but I'd like to know the real intention.

Comment: upon further review, draft 01 of the spec (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-01) describes the method the same as in the http-signing.md readme file. So it looks like the `(request-target)` is preferred. I haven't evaluated the npm module to see what it really uses. (in other words, to see if it agrees with the http-signing readme, or if it complies with draft 03 of the spec)